# How to combine below two grep commands

Tags: linux, grep

How to combine below two grep commands,

```
echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -oc ${dev_id1})
echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -oc ${dev_id2})
```

so far tried below but not worked,

```
echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -oc ${dev_id1}|${dev_id2})
echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -oc ${dev_id1}\|${dev_id2})
```

Comment: Looks like you want to count matches of `$dev_id1` and `$dev_id2`, if `echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -oc "${dev_id1}\\|${dev_id2}"` does not work, try `echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -Eoc "${dev_id1}|${dev_id2}"`, else, the grep you are using is broken.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
echo $(pci -nd ${vendor_id1}: | grep -Eoc "${dev_id1}|${dev_id2}"
```

`-E` option allows the POSIX ERE syntax that supports unescaped `|` as an alternation operator.

Pay attention at the double quotation marks around the regex string, it allows variable expansion.